# How to go from RepeatedField to a list or array?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

I have a RepeatedField, which i need to Convert to a .NET List or Array.

How can this be done?
Is there a better way than taking each element and putting into a new list using a forEach? This seems to be quite a performance hit when dealing with huge data sets.

Example,
I want this to become a

```
List<string>
```

```
message keysList {
    repeated string keys = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using protobuf-net be an option? Since it is code-first, you can do what you want:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
class Whatever {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<string> TheData {get;set;}
}
```